# Beyond "That" Meaning

Tags: word-meaning, parts-of-speech

I can’t understand what is the meaning of "that" in the following sentence:

> ...she felt sad that she didn't see them more often...

Are "that" and "because" both words synonyms?

Comment: In this specific example they are synonyms, but *that* has many other meanings/functions in English.

Comment: @Giambattista: Why not write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The word that can be tricky as it has many functions. In your example specifically, it is synonymous with because. This, however, is not universally true. That is functioning as a conjunction here joining the two clauses.